# Ruby gem for checking screen for matching images?

Tags: ruby

I've been googling this for days and the only thing I can find is Sikuli, which is java, and my experience with Sikuli in the past was somewhat negative. Is there a different library that would do screen checking for images?

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli uses Jython, so you can take libs from sikuli and write script at python. We did some project that way.
Or you can take these .jars and write an JRuby. 
for example: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sikuli/0.3.0